# "to throw an idea in the room" - Does it exist?

Tags: idioms, phrases

Does the phrase "to throw an idea in the room" for "having wild ideas" exist?

We have an expression like this in German, but it sounds odd to me in English.

Example: He doesn't really think about what he is saying. He just throws any idea in the room.

Comment: There are many such idioms.  American corporatespeak is often ridiculed for them.

Comment: Well, it would be understood. The concept of "throwing ideas" certainly exists. No need to mention "the room" though.  We can also say "to throw some ideas around". Maybe you could reword it "He just throws random ideas around".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an expression dealing with a multitude of ideas, only some of which might be any use.

> To throw ideas at the wall

The full version of which, sometimes unstated, is

> To throw ideas at the wall and see which ones stick.

The general meaning is that not all the ideas are good enough to stay attached to the wall, only the better ones. The poor ones will just fall to the floor where they can be ignored or forgotten.

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard it used with "in the room" but yes, English speakers do throw ideas out there:

> to produce something such as ideas or questions in large quantities:
> *Members of the team threw out ideas.*
> — [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/throw-out)

> (idiomatic) To offer an idea for consideration.
> *Let me throw this out there – how about if we make the igloo out of butter? Would that work?*
> — [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/throw_out#:%7E:text=(idiomatic)%20To%20offer%20an%20idea,produce%20in%20a%20haphazard%20fashion.)

There's an implication that the ideas might be [out there](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/out-there) (an unrelated expression: "an idea, work of art etc that is out there is so unusual that it might seem silly or extreme") but you can also say "[I am just throwing a **wild** idea out there](https://www.reddit.com/r/DragonballLegends/comments/jhkvqp/so_i_am_just_throwing_a_wild_idea_out_there_what/)" to emphasize that point.